# Behaviour of select() on remote socket closed(by killing process)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

Two processes are communicating via sockets - Process A and Process B.

Process B is using `select()` call to check when the socket is the ready for `I/O.`

Process A is suddenly killed. What will happen to the B side socket. Will B side socket automatically detect that A's socket is no longer available and `select()` will return -1 with `EABDF`. OR `select()` call will remain blocked forever.

Answer (score 2):

Select will unlock and either an error case or a read case will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

`select()` returns and says that the socket is readable. When you read the socket, you will get -1 (and the corresponding error in errno) or 0 (EOF).

Comment: after select() returns when read() will be called, will read () return 0 or -1.

Comment: @Sumit Trehan : It depend on TCP stack/OS of host of A. If it sends TCP-RST then read() returns -1. If it nicely use TCP-FIN, then read() return 0. My linux box seems to use FIN, when I terminate A with signal KILL (kill -9). But Windows seems to use RST. So I would handle the both situation in the code of B.

Answer (score -1):

The tcp socket will remain half opened for some time if there's no heartbeat between two sides.
Finally tcp connection will time out, depends on the time out settings.
Refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-open_connection

Comment: Timeout why? Where in your Wikipedia reference does it say that? Why are you quoting non-normative references instead of RFCs?